# "\n" not working with MailApp.sendEmail, also not with GmailApp.sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

No breaks my wooden-shoe (is a saying in the Netherlands) which means, now i go crazy:

I have a google script where "\n" is not working with MailApp.sendEmail. In an other script i used \n too with the MailApp.sendEmail and there it is working! I already tried GmailApp.sendEmail, same problem.

Comment: Probably because you're using `htmlBody` instead of plain text body parameter. On HTML line breaks are ignored by design.

Comment: YES! Thank you. i did not notice the htmlbody paramater because it is code i copied from an example.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu answer it below :)

Comment: I usually don't write single-line answers. Specially a "guess" one, since there's no code in the question. But due to the amount of votes it got, I guess I'll follow your recommendation @Zig

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're using `htmlBody` instead of plain text body parameter. In HTML line-breaks are ignored by design.